# Ya no funciona más aplicación de validación

Tags: android, validación

Uso Android Studio 3, estoy haciendo un tutorial, la aplicación según la venía yo haciendo funcionaba, pero cuando puse lo que va desde

```
btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

hacia abajo, ya no funciona más, en mi celular se inicia y se detiene de inmediato.

MainActivity

```
    package com.example.jhon.validacionesenandroid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtCorreo, txtPas;
    Button btnIniciar;
    TextInputLayout impCorreo, ImpPas;
    boolean cor=false, pas=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtCorreo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCorreo);
        txtPas=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        impCorreo=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.impCorreo);
        ImpPas=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impPassword);

        btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(txtCorreo.getText().toString()).matches()==false){
                    impCorreo.setError("Correo Inválido");
                    cor=false;
                }else{
                    cor=true;
                    impCorreo.setError(null);
                }

                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9][0-9]");

                if(p.matcher(txtPas.getText().toString()).matches()==false){
                    ImpPas.setError("Password inválido");
                    pas=false;
                }else{
                    pas=true;
                    ImpPas.setError(null);
                }

                if(cor==true && pas==true){
                    String usuario=txtCorreo.getText().toString();
                    String clave=txtPas.getText().toString();

                   if(usuario.equals("jhon") && clave.equals("12")){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Principal.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uusario o password incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Logueo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/impPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/impCorreo">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtCorreo" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnIniciar"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:text="Iniciar Sesión"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/impPassword" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/impCorreo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtCorreo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_principal.xm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="166dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="Bienvenido"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Mi gradle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="166dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="Bienvenido"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da en la consola? Míralo porque estas intentando escuchar el onclick de un elemento que no has asociado con la vista (btnIniciar).

Comment: Pues error como tal no me sale, esto es del log: 07:05 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

07:05 AM Gradle build finished in 13s 11ms

Comment: No he hecho una asociación... ¿qué debería cambiar? Carmen

Comment: como te ha dicho carmen te falta la declaración del botón, es decir: btnIniciar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIniciar);

Comment: Justo lo que te dice @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que en tu btnIniciar esta declarado como variable pero no se ha hecho referencia a el xml que lo contiene, solo debe agregar

```
btnIniciar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIniciar);
```

ya luego podras ejecutar su funcion onClick

Answer (score 0):

Estas declarando la variable y posteriormente asignas un listener, el problema es que aquí la variable `btnIniciar` tendrá valor null:

```
Button btnIniciar;
    ...
    ...
    btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //
        }
    });
    ...
    ...
```

antes de asignar alguna propiedad o listener a tu botón, debes obtener la referencia mediante:

y posteriormente podrás asignar el listener `OnClickListener`:

```
...
...
btnIniciar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIniciar);

btnIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //
    }
});
...
...
```